# Regularity of solutions to a quadratic program?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, regularization

Consider the map $ A : K \subset \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, with $K$ compact and convex, defined by

$$
A(c) = \text{arg}\min_{y \succeq 0} y^TDy + c^T y
$$

Where $D$ is a positive semidefinite (not positive definite) matrix, and c is a vector.  Also, suppose $D$ and $c$ are always such that there is a unique minimum so $A$ is a well-defined function.  It can be shown that $A$ is continuous in this case.

> Question: Is the map $A$ Lipschitz continuous?

I'm not too familiar with optimization techniques in general, and my naïve attempts to answer this question have so far failed.  E.g. without the non-negatovity constraint, the answer is true, but I cannot figure out how to relate that to the constrained case.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!